# jqGrid Disable Date Picker Value for Inline Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.4. I have a date picker for a column and it returns today's date. I only need it to default to today's date for the add modal pop-up. However, when someone is editing a record inline, I need the date not to change to today's date when the user clicks into a record to edit inline.

This is causing data integrity issues, because when a user edits an existing record, the date changes to today's date.

How can I keep it the way it is for adding a new record through the modal, while preventing it from defaulting when inline editing?

Here is the code with the datepicker in the edit options:

```
 { key: false, name: 'CHK_DT_RCVD', width: '130px', index: 'CHK_DT_RCVD',
            editable: true, formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' },
            formoptions: {},
            editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validDateCheck },

            editoptions:
            {

                dataInit: function (element)
                {
                    $(element).datepicker({

                        id: 'entryDate_Datepicker',
                        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
                        maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                        showOn: 'focus'
                    }).val(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
                }
             }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should initialize `datepicker` inside of `setTimeout`. The problem: the `dataInit` could be (will be) called *before* `element` be placed on the HTML page (`element` is disconnected DOM element).

Inside of `setTimeout` you can travel over the parents of `element` and to try to find out whether the element is inside of `tr.jqgrow` or not. If `$(element).closest("tr.jqgrow").length > 0` then the datepicker is inside of inline editing (or cell editing). You should not use `.val(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));` in the case.

Additionally you can consider to use `defaultValue` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). It will be used in Add dialog of form editing. Probably you will be not need to use any `.val(...)` after the specifing of `defaultValue`.

By the way, I'd recommend you to remove unneeded `key: false` and `index: 'CHK_DT_RCVD'` properties and to fix `width: '130px'` to `width: 130` because the value of `width` have to be integer.